# Concatenate inside SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, case

I am moving a customer database which has a First Name, Last Name and Company Name. The current data will either have a First & Last Name or a Company name

In the new database I have a "Print Name" field which I need to combine the first and last name into, or if there is a company name present I need to use this value.

I have tried the bellow CASE WHEN expression to no avail.

```
SELECT 
fstnam,
lstnam,
cmpnam,
CASE
    WHEN csttbl.cmpnam = null THEN fstnam||' '||lstnam
    ELSE csttbl.cmpnam
    END as PrintName

FROM csttbl;
```

With the above query I only have a company name return in the print name column, not the combined First & Last Name. the returned data can be seen here https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B31ZRmFSX6rMYmNOczlRNE1lM2c

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT fstnam, lstnam, cmpnam,
       COALESCE(csttbl.cmpnam, fstnam|| ' ' || lstnam) as PrintName
FROM csttbl;
```

Comment: Didn't think of just concatonating the whole string as there is no First & Last name if there is a company name. COALESCE doesn't seem to work for me though so did the below
    SELECT fstnam, lstnam, cmpnam,
           csttbl.cmpnam||fstnam|| ' ' ||lstnam as PrintName
    FROM csttbl;

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
csttbl.cmpnam = null
```

To

```
csttbl.cmpnam is null
```

RDBMS cannot compare `null` to any value, so using `=` with null is of no use. To compare nulls you should use `is null` which works on almost all RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't think of just concatonating the whole string as there is no First & Last name if there is a company name. COALESCE doesn't seem to work for me though so did the below

```
SELECT 
fstnam, 
lstnam, 
cmpnam, 
csttbl.cmpnam||fstnam|| ' ' ||lstnam as PrintName 
FROM csttbl;
```